# Зачем gcc во всех объектных файлах оставляет строку вида "GCC: (tdm-1) 4.9.2"

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Зачем `gcc` во всех объектных файлах оставляет строку вида `GCC: (tdm-1) 4.9.2` и как это отключить? Какие ключи применять?

Comment: Какую проблему хотите решить?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы этой строки небыло  в объектных файлах.

Comment: компилятор ведет себя иногда так, как обычный хулиган, который оставляет после себя "здесь был GCC tdm". Можно конечно попробовать обработать бинарник утилитой strip, которая обычно идет с компилятором и она подчистит большинство таких строк.